# Button doesn't work: E/To: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

Tags: android, button

I'm going mad with that:

I'm using API LEVEL 23 and when and I click in a button, following log appears:

```
E/To: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{5af3e42 VFED..C.. ...PH... 161,642-469,810 #7f0c0070 app:id/btSaveAC1}
```

and doesn't work. Any idea please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/gradiant_fons"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActividadesJava.Interno.Actividades">


<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtDesc"

    android:hint="Nombre Actividad"
    android:text="Actividad"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDataInicio"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtHoraInici"
        android:hint="Hora Inicio"
        android:text="11:00"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtHiraFi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtHiraFi"
        android:hint="Hora Fin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDesc"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cbSabado"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtHoraInici"
        android:text="12:00" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="LU"
        android:id="@+id/cbLunes"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHoraInici" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MA"
        android:id="@+id/cbMartes"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btSaveAC1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHoraInici" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MI"
        android:id="@+id/cbMiercoles"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cbMartes"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbMartes"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="JU"
        android:id="@+id/cbJueves"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cbMiercoles"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbMiercoles"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VI"
        android:id="@+id/cbViernes"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cbJueves"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbJueves"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SA"
        android:id="@+id/cbSabado"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cbViernes"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbViernes"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DO"
        android:id="@+id/cbDomingo"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cbSabado"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cbSabado"
        android:textColor="#f9f7f7"
        android:buttonTint="#214111"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="GUARDAR AC"
        android:id="@+id/btSaveAC1"
        android:textColor="#fcfafa"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbLunes"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cbLunes" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtDataInicio"
        android:text="12/12/2007"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtDataFin"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cbDomingo"
        android:text="21/12/2058" />

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="169dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvActividades"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cbDomingo"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Actividades.class

```
public class Actividades extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {


private Button mSaveAC;
private ArrayList<Actividad> ActivitatsArrayRecibidos = new ArrayList<Actividad>();
private AdaptadorMetasLista adapter;
private Actividad newActividad;
private EditText mtxtDesc;
private EditText mtxtHoraInici;
private EditText mtxtDataInicio;
private EditText mtxDataFin;
private EditText mtxtHoraFi;
private CheckBox mcbLunes;
private CheckBox mcbMartes;
private CheckBox mcbMiercoles;
private CheckBox mcbJueves;
private CheckBox mcbViernes;
private CheckBox mcbSabado;
private CheckBox mcbDomingo;
private ListView mListView;
private String userOBID;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividades);

    mSaveAC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSaveAC1);

    mtxtDesc= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
    mtxtHoraInici= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtHoraInici);
    mtxtDataInicio= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtDataInicio);
    mtxDataFin= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtDataFin);
    mtxtHoraFi= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtHiraFi);
    mcbLunes= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbLunes);
    mcbMartes= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbMartes);
    mcbMiercoles= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbMiercoles);
    mcbJueves= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbJueves);
    mcbViernes= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbViernes);
    mcbSabado= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbSabado);
    mcbDomingo= (CheckBox) this.findViewById(R.id.cbDomingo);
    mListView= (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.lvActividades);

mSaveAC.setOnClickListener(this);
    Log.e("creant inci", "AC");


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_notificacions, menu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    //      getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String opcio = item.getTitle().toString(); //ITem seleccionat
    Log.e("Opcio_", opcio);
    if (opcio.equals("Salir")){// Lanzar Salir

        Sortir();
    }
   else
    {//Cridem a la classe Menuopcions
        Log.e("MENU_", "MENU OPCIONS");
        MenuOpcions nMO=new MenuOpcions();
        final Context context = this; //creem un context final que será el comntexte actual
        nMO.Selecció(opcio, context,this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Sortir(){
    Log.e("MENU_", "SALIR");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("¿Quieres Salir de MyTime?")
            .setTitle("Advertencia")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton("Continuar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}



public void onClick(View v) {




    if (v==mSaveAC) {
        Log.e("To",v.toString() );
        this.GuardarActividad();

    }

}



public Boolean CargarActividades(){

  final Boolean[] mValorRetorno = {false};
    BackendlessUser user= Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
    String whereClause = "propietarioId = '"+ user.getObjectId().toString() +"'";
    Log.e("WC",whereClause);

    final BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    dataQuery.setWhereClause( whereClause );

    Backendless.Data.of(Actividad.class).find(dataQuery,new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Actividad>>() {

        @Override

        public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Actividad> valors) {
            System.out.println( valors.getCurrentPage().toString());

            for( Actividad order : valors.getCurrentPage() )
            {
                System.out.println( order );

                ActivitatsArrayRecibidos.add(order );

            }
            mValorRetorno[0]=true;
            Log.e("Query","ok");
            CargarTabla();

        }

        @Override

        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
            mValorRetorno[0]=false;

        }

    });


    Log.e("Retorno",mValorRetorno[0].toString());
    return mValorRetorno[0];

}
public void CargarTabla()

{
    Log.e("Cargando tabla",Integer.toString(ActivitatsArrayRecibidos.size()));

   Log.e("Cargando desc", ActivitatsArrayRecibidos.get(0).getdesc());

  AdaptadorActividadesLista adt = new AdaptadorActividadesLista(this, ActivitatsArrayRecibidos);
 mListView.setAdapter(adt);
}
public boolean ComprovarCampos()
{
    return true;
}


public void GuardarActividad(){

    if (ComprovarCampos()==true) {
        Log.e("Creant Activitat  ","");
        BackendlessUser user= Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser();
        newActividad = new Actividad();
        newActividad.setactiva(true);
        newActividad.setdesc(mtxtDesc.getText().toString());

        newActividad.setfechafin(ConvertirFecha(mtxDataFin.getText().toString()));
        newActividad.setfechainicio(ConvertirFecha(mtxtDataInicio.getText().toString()));

        newActividad.sethorafin(ConvertirFecha(mtxtHoraFi.getText().toString()));
        newActividad.sethorainicio(ConvertirFecha(mtxtHoraInici.getText().toString()));

        newActividad.setLunes(mcbLunes.isChecked());
        newActividad.setmartes(mcbMartes.isChecked());
        newActividad.setmiercoles(mcbMiercoles.isChecked());
        newActividad.setjueves(mcbJueves.isChecked());
        newActividad.setviernes(mcbViernes.isChecked());
        newActividad.setsabado(mcbSabado.isChecked());
        newActividad.setdomingo(mcbDomingo.isChecked());
        newActividad.setpropietarioId(user.getObjectId());
        Log.e("Objecte creat ","");
        // save object asynchronously
        Backendless.Persistence.save( newActividad, new AsyncCallback<Actividad>() {

            public void handleResponse( Actividad response )
            {
                Log.e("Objecte desat ","");
            }

            public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
            {
                Log.e("Objecte No desat ","");
            }
        });
    }

}

public String ConvertirFecha(String fecha){
    return fecha;
}
```

Comment: full logcat please. you don't explain your problem except doesn't work which is very vague for anyone to help with

Answer (score 0):

In your XML you use a button from the support library (widget.AppCompatButton), but in your code you're trying to cast it to a regular Button. Either use the regular Button in your XML code, or use the AppCompatButton in the Java code.

Seeing that you are using the support library (you're using the AppCompatActivity), I'd advice you to change 'Button' to 'AppCompatButton' in your Java code.

Comment: Use `Button` in both places. The whole purpose of AppCompat is not to have your code be aware of the difference.

Comment: @Karakuri What about the cases where you need to use functionality that is only available in the AppCompatButton class and not in the Button class?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. It's a very thin shim class that backports tinting and little else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mates.

I solved. It was a Backendless error, and the Logs. I din't fill the second argument and for that raason error didnt appear.